# listbox - operation from within DoWork thread

Tags: c#

I need to update a listbox from within a BG Worker DoWork(). I created a generic thread safe function like this (for use from inside dll):

```
private delegate void AddListBoxItemDelegate(ListBox lst, object item);

public static void AddListBoxItem(ListBox lst, object item)
{
    if (lst.InvokeRequired)
    {

        lst.Invoke(new AddListBoxItemDelegate(AddListBoxItem), item);
    }
    else
    {
        lst.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

It's not working, invalid argument list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the `ListBox lst` as well:

```
lst.Invoke(new AddListBoxItemDelegate(AddListBoxItem), lst, item);
```

...because your delegate signature is `AddListBoxItem(ListBox lst, object item)`.